# Paint segments on spaceships

Tags: uv, texture-painting, displacement

I would like to create a segmented look of my spaceship with hatches and paneled armor segments. I have the outline of it already modeled, but I am lost how to create the segments. I don't want to model them, I would much rather paint them on with a texture.

UV unwrapping gives me a texture, but painting the UV externally makes it very difficult to figure out what the final distortion will be.

How can I paint on nice, straight geometric lines directly onto the model?

[image: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71PRh3ntD8L._SX425_.jpg]

Comment: How much experience do you have with texture paint in Blender so far? There are resources online on how to paint a bump map, and that might be what you are looking for, but the overall scope of learning all that is necessary to paint these details properly in the 3d view is a lot to try to explain. I could try to make a simple breakdown, but if you haven't gotten into painting in Blender yet, this could be too advanced.

Comment: I can manage the draw a texture in the 3d, what I am missing is how to force geometric shapes

Comment: have you thought about modeling them with some extrudes and then bake to make a normal map? It would take time, but painting would as well

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is preferable, but at least you can make something happen with bump if you want.
First we set up our object to paint, and set up a 4k image texture to the Bump slot of our object, checking the box to use Float.
[image]
Next we turn on Face select masking so that we can make a selection while in texture paint.
[image]
Next we use View>Align to View>Top to get our object view to the top of the selection so we can make as straight a curve as possible.
[image]
After setting stroke method to 'Curve', use ctrl-click to set points along the features you want from view, making sure to follow the curve of the underlying wireframe as reference.
[image]
Turn off Face select masking, and press the Return key to stroke the curve - I use a small brush radius here, but be careful not to zoom in and out because that will mean a lot of variation in stroke width.
Lastly, you can preview the result after switching to Object mode, and then determine if you need to invert the color of your texture to get the opposite direction. White is up, Black is down, and grey is middle.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A new way occurred to me - you can draw on the surface with Grease Pencil strokes and then convert them to disconnected curves, and then give them some depth in the curves panel - then bake the main object with AO to get a black and white mask (sorta) to use for lines - also on the left, the curves actually look cool too.

[image]